# Drawing shapes in python (turtle)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to draw a rectangle a rectangle using this function:

drawRectangle(myTurtle, x, y, height, width, lineColor, fillColor)

where the left-top corner coordinate is (x,y)

code i have so far:

```
def drawSquare(myTurtle,sideLength):
    for i in range(4):
        myTurtle.forward(sideLength)
        myTurtle.right(90)


def drawRectangle():



 import turtle
 t= turtle.Turtle()

 t.color('blue')
 t.fillcolor('yellow')
 t.begin_fill()

 drawRectangle(myTurtle, x, y, height, width, lineColor, fillColor)

 t.end_fill()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're making a turtle `t`, then completely ignoring it and passing to `drawRectangle` a turtle (?) that you have actually never made at all.

Obviously, you'll need to pass to the function exactly the turtle you have made, not another!  Moreover, the `color` and `fillColor` you've set on the turtle you make are irrelevant, since `drawRectangle` is clearly meant to do its own settings for those attributes, from the arguments it gets.

Next, you have a `def drawRectangle():` without any argument while at the very start of the text you've already laid out the arguments it must have -- just copy and paste that line from the text to the code (with a `def` in front of course), surely you don't need others' help for that!

Next, you don't have any body in that `def` which is a syntax error -- if you don't know yet what to write there, put in a `pass` indented for spaces.

Next, all lines from `import turtle` to the end are incorrectly indented one space when they should be flush left -- remove those spaces.

Next, you're calling `drawRectangle(myTurtle, x, y, height, width, lineColor, fillColor)` passing in **seven** variables that you have never set to anything at all.  Assign something to each of those variables before you make that call!

Fix these half a dozen obvious bugs first, by editing your Q appropriately, then we can keep helping...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Pen() #the "P" in Pen must be capital.
for i in range(700):
    bob.forward(i)
    bob.left(80)
    bob.forward(50)
    bob.right(i)
    bob.back(50)
    bob.left(i)
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to explain why this is a solution.

Comment: Simply posting a code answer doesn't do the OP any good. Give some sort of insight into your answer.